# Query returns nothing through PHP

Tags: php, sqlsrv

I'm having trouble with my SQL query running through PHP. This is my code

```
$username = $_POST['username'];

$SQLString = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Users WHERE Username = '$username'";
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $SQLString) or die (print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
$userExists = sqlsrv_fetch_object( $result );

echo("test");
echo($userExists);
echo("test2");
```

This returns `testtest2`, and nothing for $userExists. This seemed to work last night, and I haven't changed anything besides printing out the sqlsrv errors, but those don't return anything.

`$result` returns `Resource id #3`, and I'm able to run an insert later in my code.

Can anyone see why `$userExists` returns nothing at all? I thought that it would have to return 0 at the very least (if the user does not exist).

**EDIT**

So attempting using prepared statements that chris85 recommended, and again it spits out the exact same thing. `$stmt` returns `Resource ID #2`, and $userExists returns absolutely nothing. No failures, no errors.

```
$SQLString = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Users WHERE Username = '$username'";
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare( $conn, $SQLString, array( &$qty, &$id));
$userExists = sqlsrv_fetch_object( $stmt);
if( !$stmt ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

echo("test");
print_r($stmt);
print_r($userExists);   
echo("test2");
```

Comment: Try `print_r($userExists)` to see if it is set; it is an object not a string, http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-object.php. I'm not familiar with the `sqlsrv_` functions but you should use prepared statements. Try http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-prepare.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-execute.php. Your current code is open to injections as is prepared statements will resolve that.

Comment: `print_r($userExists)` returns the same thing - nothing at all. And yep, I know it's open to injections, I'm just trying a proof of concept thing at the moment. I'll give the prepared statements a shot and see what happens.

Comment: Prepared statements didn't do anything for me... see edits. Any other ideas on things I can try? Otherwise I'm just going to rewrite it all from scratch and see what happens

Comment: I'm not sure off hand but maybe giving the column an alias and then calling the alias from the object would work? `SELECT COUNT(*) as usercounter FROM dbo.Users WHERE Username = '$username'` then later `echo $userExists->usercounter;`. Also I think the prepared statement is wrong. The variable should be a placeholder. Here's a blog on that in mssql http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_swan/archive/2010/03/04/what_2700_s-the-right-way-to-avoid-sql-injection-in-php-scripts_3f00_.aspx

Comment: Oh, I see - rather than passing the variables directly into the query, you load them into an array and pass them through using the sqlsrv_query method. I'll give it a shot!

Comment: Hey there, if you managed to solve your own problem. Feel free to "answer your own question". That way, others who might have the same problem, can see how you solved it!